# Regex for Contact in a python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which contains data including contacts. Some of the contact examples are "+92 42 111-865-865" , "(+92) 42 3256 0445" , "03325138889" ,"0332 5138889" , "+92 332 5138889" , "+92 3325138889". I need to create a regex for the contacts

I have tried some regex such as but there are some other data in same string such as: "48358982872144","100220100","36470002". My regex wrongly list these as contacts.

```
 import re
 strdata = " Some Data here "
 contactRegex = re.compile("^[+][(][0-9][0-9][)]|[+][0-9][0-9]|[0,4]|[-/0-9]*$")
 contactlist = contactRegex.findall(strdata)
```

Comment: A more complete example of the input and how the pattern fails on it will be very helpful. For the mean time, use [this demo](https://regex101.com/) website to see how exactly your pattern works on different input strings

Comment: I have mentioned it above. some contact examples are  (+92 42 111-865-865" , "(+92) 42 3256 0445" , "03325138889" ,"0332 5138889" , "+92 332 5138889" , "+92 3325138889) these are valid contacts. Invalid contacts : ("48358982872144","100220100","36470002") if i put valid contacts in variable strdata in my code, the regex list them as contacts but my remove some character in that example at output. also if i put invalid contacts  in that variable to text. Regex list these as valid contacts.

Comment: read in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially the part about a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will probably explain it better than me. Try to explain your requierments better. What is considered valid, what is not. All I see is a bunch of numbers which some of them are good for you and some are not with no apparant logic...

Comment: Try `^(?:(?:\(\+92\)|\+92) (?:42|332)|0332) ?\d+(?:([ -])\d+(?:\1\d+)*)?$`  https://regex101.com/r/Q2Z6fy/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match your example data, you might use:

```
^(?:(?:\(\+92\)|\+92) (?:42|332)|0332) ?\d+(?:([ -])\d+(?:\1\d+)*)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:\(\+92\)|\+92))` Match either +(92) or +92
  - `(?:42|332)` Match space and one of the options
  - `|` Or
  - `0332` Match literally
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `?\d+` Match an optional space and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `([ -])` Capture in group 1 either a space or dot
  - `\d+(?:\1\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and repeat 0+ times matching what is captured in group 1 using a backreference to get consisten spaces or hyphens and not combined
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q2Z6fy/1)